# Linear mixed-effect models (nlme/ lme4) interpretation of marginal and conditional R^2 values

Tags: r, lme4, nlme, glmm

I'm investigating bacterial diversity and want wo know if the diversity is dependent on the pH. My data are structured as followed:

- I have a dataset of 17 different studies
- each study has values for diversity and for pH (the number of values differ between the   studies)

Now I am searching for a way to answer the question "Is there a effect of the pH on the diversity throughout all studies"

The idea was to use the function `lme` and set study as random factor. Looking at the data they seem to rather fit a quadratic term than a linear regression, so I tried to calculate the model also with the quadratic term of the pH:

```r
my_model<- lme( fixed = Bacterial_diversity ~ pH +
I(pH^2),
random = ~ pH |Study,
data= my_data)
```

The output (summary) is:

```r
> summary(my_model)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: my_data
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  471.7855 497.7353 -228.8928

Random effects:
 Formula: ~pH | Paper
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 4.4808759 (Intr)
pH          0.4783127 -0.88 
Residual    0.4154606       

Fixed effects:  Bacterial_diversity ~ pH + I(pH^2) 
                 Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  1.6641091 1.8078372 285  0.920497  0.3581
pH           1.1750097 0.4670426 285  2.515851  0.0124
I(pH^2)     -0.1187954 0.0363455 285 -3.268508  0.0012
 Correlation: 
        (Intr) pH    
pH      -0.895       
I(pH^2)  0.763 -0.959

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-4.2091539 -0.4574020  0.1168270  0.6216446  2.0828655 

Number of Observations: 304
Number of Groups: 17
```

I don't really know how to interpret these results. When I use `tab_model(my_model)` I end up with two R^2 values. The marginal R^2 (0.025) and the conditional R^2 (0.974), the given p-value is 0.0012 (for the quadratic term of pH) and 0.0124 (for the pH).
Are the R^2 values calculated for the whole model? and how can I interpret the R^2 values? Can I say that my data are more likely to fit a quadratic term than a linear regression (due to the more significant p value of the pH^2)?

Is even the model I used the right one or should I have used nlme instead of lme4 (I don't really understand the difference!).

I just want to show the relation between the pH and the bacterial diversity with respect to the different studies

If you have any ideas this would help a lot.
And if there are questions regarding the data, the code or anything else, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Model interpretation questions belong on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ... this question may get closed/migrated, if it doesn't you could delete and re-post there. In the meantime, it would help if you could edit your question to include the output summary in a text form (cut-and-pasted text, in a code block) rather than as a screenshot (not searchable, inaccessible to screen readers ...)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post and hope the summary output is now available.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary and Citations

I recommend using the `performance` package or even the `partR2` package, which use the Nakagawa R2 values of marginal and conditional R2 that you mention. I also advise reading these three papers on the subject, which explain what the values are:

- [Nakagawa et al., 2013: Original Pseudo R2 value paper.](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x)
- [Nakagawa et al., 2017: Extension of Pseudo R2 values.](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213)
- [Stoffel et al., 2021: Part R2 values.](https://10.7717/peerj.11414)

#### Fitting a Model

I provide  worked example with these values and explanations below. First, I load the required packages and model below. For simplicity, I drop the NA values here, but these should be handled with care in a real scenario.

```
#### Libraries ####
library(lmerTest) # for model fitting
library(performance) # for Nakagawa conditional/marginal R2
library(partR2) # for part R2 values
library(tidyverse) # for tidying data

#### Remove NA Values ####
carrots <- carrots %>% 
  drop_na()

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lmer(Preference 
           ~ sens2 
           + Homesize 
           + (1 | Consumer),
           data=carrots)
```

#### Marginal and Conditional R2

Then we can run a simple summary of pseudo R2.

```
#### Run Pseudo R2 and Part R2 ####
r2_nakagawa(fit)
```

Which gives us this:

```
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.176
     Marginal R2: 0.064
```

Conditional R2 is the amount of explained variance for the entire model. In this case, both the fixed and random effects explain about 17.6% of the variance of the outcome. The marginal R2 explains how much of this variance is attributed to the fixed effects alone. Here it is a fairly small amount: .064%.

#### Individual Effects: Part R2

However, this doesn't speak much to the individual effects. For this, `partR2` can help answer this question (to a degree). Notice that if you have missing data or random slopes that match the fixed effects, the `partR2` function will kick back an error. I have set the boots to 100, but they should be closer to 1000 for a final model (I only do this to save time and computation).

```
part <- partR2(fit,
       partvars = c("sens2",
                    "Homesize"),
       nboot = 100)
```

Here you get a summary of the fixed effect sizes here:

```
summary(part)
```

Seen below. You'll notice that it automatically provides a marginal R2, which matches with the total partR2 of `sens2+Homesize`:

```
R2 (marginal) and 95% CI for the full model: 
 R2     CI_lower CI_upper ndf
 0.0643 0.0407   0.0964   3  

----------

Part (semi-partial) R2:
 Predictor(s)   R2     CI_lower CI_upper ndf
 Model          0.0643 0.0407   0.0964   3  
 sens2          0.0498 0.0262   0.0818   2  
 Homesize       0.0145 0.0000   0.0461   2  
 sens2+Homesize 0.0643 0.0407   0.0964   1  

----------

Inclusive R2 (SC^2 * R2):
 Predictor IR2    CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2     0.0498 0.0307   0.0729  
 Homesize3 0.0145 0.0016   0.0401  

----------

Structure coefficients r(Yhat,x):
 Predictor SC      CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2      0.8804  0.6980   0.9834 
 Homesize3 -0.4749 -0.7164  -0.1814 

----------

Beta weights (standardised estimates)
 Predictor BW      CI_lower CI_upper
 sens2      0.2235  0.1754   0.2703 
 Homesize3 -0.2800 -0.4716  -0.0914 

----------
```

Here we can see that `sens2` contributes more to the model than home size based off the higher explained variance. For more information, refer to the articles I have included above.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shawn Hemelstrand this already helped a lot. I will take a closer look at your example and also read into the references to understand how to interpret the R2 values in detail.

Comment: Great. Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if you feel it was helpful.